# How Can I calculate the sum of a specific column using bash?

Tags: bash, sum

I want to calculate the sum of a specific column using bash without using the print that specific column (I want to keep all the output columns of my pipeline and only sum one of them!)

Comment: Show example, a few lines of input and desired output.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you wanted to sum over, say, the second column, but print all columns in some pipeline:

```
cat data | awk '{sum+=$2 ; print $0} END{print "sum=",sum}'
```

If the file data looks like:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Then the output would be:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
sum= 15
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to continuously sum one column, step by step?

Does is have to be `bash` or can you use `awk`:

```
# file 'fields.txt':
1 foo
2 bar
10 baz
8 boz

# Step by step sum the first column:
awk '{s+=$1; print s, $2}' < fields.txt

# Output:
1 foo
3 bar
13 baz
21 boz
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the same input data as @John1024, you can use good ol' `cut` and `paste` and some [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) arithmetic:

```
$ cat data | echo $(( $( cut -d' ' -f2 | paste -s -d+ - ) ))
15
$
```

The trick here is to tell `paste` to insert `+` as a delimiter, then perform bash arithmetic using `$(( ))` on the resulting expression.

Note I am just `cat`ing the input data for illustrative purposes - it could be piped from another source, or the data file passed directly to `cut` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sum+=$1;} END { print "Total of 1st Column:" sum }1' abc.t6RrMm
```

Given a file like:

```
12 12 12 
1  1  1
2  2  1
0  1  2
```

Total of 1st Column is `15`.